# C++ Qt PgSQL custom character in database

Tags: c++, database, qt, postgresql

I wrote a database update program. The problem is that *value* is the QString, which may include **'** in some cases. It must not be removed.
Here is the code:

```cpp
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(9999);
db.setDatabaseName("name");
db.setUserName("someone");
QSqlQuery q;
q = db.exec("UPDATE " + arr + " SET " + name + " = '" + value + "' WHERE question_id = "+ id);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use parameters (or placeholders):

```
QSqlQuery q = QSqlQuery(db);
q.prepare("UPDATE " + arr + " SET " + name + " = :name WHERE question_id = :id");
q.bindValue(":name", value);
q.bindValue(":id", id);
q.exec();
```

It is better to always use parameters to pass any value to your queries. Appending values to query string, is subject to sql injection attack, and also may not always work (as in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

The `'` must be escaped by doubling it. Use the driver to do it as shown in the MD.Unicorn's answer.